# Create array based on conditional logic of values in other arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an np array(series?) with numbers ranging from 1 to 100, I have a second array with some random numbers. Both arrays are the same length. I'd like to create a 3rd array that has a 1 if array2[i] > array1[i], 0 if array2[i] = array1[i] and -1 if array2[i] < array1[i].

I can easily do this with a for loop and some "if" statements but the processing time is more then I can afford.

Please excuse the way I've written this out, I am fairly new to python and asking questions in stackoverflow. Your help is much appreciated.

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array2 = [5,8,2,4,9,3,0,2,8,5]
array3 = [1,1,-1,0,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Comment: Can you add an example for both arrays please?

Comment: array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], array2 = [5,8,2,4,9,3,0,2,8,5], array3 should look like this = [1,1,-1,0,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]

Answer (score 8):

This seems like a good use case for [`np.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html), which turns positive numbers into 1, zero to 0, and negative to -1:

```
>>> array1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
>>> array2 = np.array([5,8,2,4,9,3,0,2,8,5])
>>> np.sign(array2-array1)
array([ 1,  1, -1,  0,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])
```

Comment: TIL `np.sign` is a thing. This is by far the best answer.

Comment: We have a winner. :)

Comment: I figured it could be this simple, thanks for the help.

Comment: I've just tried this answer compared to Christoph Terasa's answer and it takes 0.005 seconds longer this route FYI.

Comment: Weird, according to my tests using ipython's `%timeit` magic this solutions is the fastest.

Comment: Yeah, i think my test of the time wasn't accurate either, doing it on a virtual server with other tasks running, my bad

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = np.array([5,8,2,4,9,3,0,2,8,5])

r = 1*(b > a) - (b < a) # multiplying by one converts boolean array to int array
print(r) # [ 1  1 -1  0  1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
```

Comment: Ohh this is clever.

Comment: Awesome, that looks like it should do the trick, thank you very much for the quick reply!

Comment: @Mitch, I liked your solution much more.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa See DSM's answer - it is an improved version of mine.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use masks:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
array2 = [5,8,2,4,9,3,0,2,8,5]

result = np.zeros(10)
# use masks
result[array2>array1 ] = 1
result[array2 ==array1 ] = 0
result[array2<array1 ] = -1

print(result) # [1,1,-1,0,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there is a faster approach, but one option would be to just subtract the first array from the second, then [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) the differences to form your comparison criteria.

```
>>> arr1 = np.array([1, 5, -3, 2, 7])
>>> arr2 = np.array([-4, 5, 3, 0, 7])
>>> np.clip(arr2-arr1, -1, 1)
array([-1,  0,  1, -1,  0])
```

**Edit**: Clipping isn't necessary because of `np.sign`, [see DSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044569/4686625).

Comment: This is about 30% faster than my solution.